# UITextField Stopped responding to user interaction

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a previously working application where you can add food items to a list

For some reason the UITextField stopped taking in input - everything else works except this UITextField.

I tried the .showasfirstresponder() method already and it still did not fix the problem - now the add food button stopped working.

It seems to be something tricky but small since my app was working at one point.

Here is my relevant code -

ViewController -

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate,
UITextFieldDelegate{

// instance vars
@IBOutlet weak var addFoodsTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var foods:[String] = []
var cellStyleForEditing: UITableViewCellEditingStyle = .none
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // nsuserdefaults setUp
        foods = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "foods") ?? [String]()
        setUpTableView()
        //addFoodsTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

func setUpTableView() {
    let containerView:UIView = UIView(frame:tableView.bounds)
    containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    containerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
    containerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    containerView.layer.shadowRadius = 5

    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nibName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableViewCell")

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(tableView)
}

@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    insertNewFoodTitle()
}

func insertNewFoodTitle() {
    foods.append(addFoodsTextField.text!)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: foods.count - 1, section: 0)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    defaults.set(foods, forKey: "foods")
    tableView.endUpdates()

    // set textFeild back to empty string
    addFoodsTextField.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}
```

And here is a pic of the interface builder - 
[image]

It was running about 30 min before I ran into this bug. I was able to add a few food items but now I cannot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happens to me since Xcode 9.

```
textfield.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
textfield.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```

Setting the BarButtonGroups this way did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is was!

It was the container view that was blocking my interactions.

Not sure what the work around is just yet but will figure it out!